# How does ultraviolet light influence the decay process of wood?

Tags: biochemistry

Given a piece of wood, how does putting it in the sun or not influence the rate of decay due to rot (assuming that it's in an otherwise humid environment)?

Comment: its not going to degrade the lignin in the wood directly that's for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Ultraviolet light is microbicidal. See [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8788/what-is-the-relationship-between-uv-wavelength-and-penetration-depth-into-human/8789#8789) post.
As I answered in this [previous](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11266/humidity-for-wood-rotting) post, micro-organisms are essential for rotting. Since UV kills these microbes it will reduce the rate of rotting. The heat from sun will also dry the wood and further decelerate rotting.